# immobilize control bar

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer

Control bar has auto hide enabled by default. I need it to be disabled. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JW6 there is only controls, which sets all controls on the display area. The value can be true or false. I'm afraid there is no option to show them at all times in this version.

Answer (score 2):

```
controlbar: {
  idlehide: false,
  position: 'bottom' // or whatever suits
}
```

Afair, this works with 5.10

Comment: In JW6 there is only controls, which sets all controls on the display area. The value can be true or false. I'm afraid there is no option to show them at all times in this version.